# What are the steps to create an Ubuntu Live CD with the Server version?

Tags: installation, boot, server, live-usb

I used the 'Startup Disk Creator' with the 12.04 LTS iso to create a bootable USB.  This worked just fine, but when it started up it gave me a menu to:

- Install Ubuntu Server
- Multiple server install with MAAS
- Check disc for defects
- Test memory
- Boot from first hard disk
- Rescue a broken system

What do I have to do to get it to boot directly into a login prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ubuntu Server there is no such thing as a Live CD, aside from the fact that if you select "Install Ubuntu Server", let it boot, and then leave it at the first install screen you can switch *virtual terminals* and get to a login prompt that way.

Normally Ctrl-Alt-F2 should switch you to a virtual terminal -- anything in the form of Ctrl-Alt-Function key where Function key is anything from F1 to F7 should work.  To switch back to the installer, try Ctrl-Alt-F1.

Comment: I especially like the hint that you already have a running (partly usable) system during the installation.